# ST_Within SQL returning too many results

Tags: sql, postgis-2.0

This ST_Within query is working fine

```
SELECT school.school_name, Courses.Course_Title, Students.No_of_Students, district.name
FROM (school INNER JOIN Students ON school.school_id = Students.School_id) INNER JOIN Courses ON Students.Course_id = Courses.Course_id, district
WHERE district.name = 'Rochdale'
AND ST_WITHIN(school.geom,district.the_geom)
```

But when I try and return another district along with 'Rochdale' it just returns loads of results

this is what I am using

```
SELECT school.school_name, Courses.Course_Title, Students.No_of_Students, district.name
FROM (school INNER JOIN Students ON school.school_id = Students.School_id) INNER JOIN Courses ON Students.Course_id = Courses.Course_id, district
WHERE district.name = 'Rochdale' or district.name = 'Calderdale'
AND ST_WITHIN(school.geom,district.the_geom)
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

You might just need some parenthesis to qualify the district name:

```
SELECT school.school_name, Courses.Course_Title, Students.No_of_Students, district.name
FROM (school INNER JOIN Students ON school.school_id = Students.School_id) INNER JOIN Courses ON Students.Course_id = Courses.Course_id, district
WHERE (district.name = 'Rochdale' or district.name = 'Calderdale')
AND ST_WITHIN(school.geom,district.the_geom)
```